# Terrible Sword and Sorcery movie

Tags: story-identification, movie

Musing over my misspent youth brings to mind a memory of a really bad sword and sorcery movie which I would love if the SF&F crew could identify for me. Things I remember:

- I would have seen it around 1985, in the UK
- Live action
- Terrible production values
- Hilariously cliched
- Standard "find the artifact" plot line
- Human warrior who has to put together a team of all the fantasy cliches, including:
- Elf with super arrow speed
- Dwarf
- Big strong barbarian (unless that was the dwarf)
- Magician who lived in a cave
- Wise woman (or maybe it was her living in the cave)
- The Elf's super-speed was done by just cutting back to an arrow loaded as soon as he had released it;
- The magician had [one of those pairs of rings set on a diagonal and spinning that look like the top one is rotating unsupported on the other](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7aVTFi5g8w) (I said the production values were bad).
- I think the word "Hunter" was either in the title or the name of the main character.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Could this be [Hawk the Slayer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080846/) from 1981?

The [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawk_the_Slayer#Plot) includes:

> Hawk locates his old friends: Gort, a giant who wields a war hammer;
> Crow, an elf who uses a bow; and Baldin, a dwarf skilled with a whip.
> The five warriors travel to at the convent and fight Voltan's men. It
> is not enough though and Voltan threatens to kill the Abbess. Voltan
> still demands the ransom. Hawk steals gold from a slave trader to pay
> the ransom.

You can see the elf doing the speed bow thing at ~1:00 in this [clip](https://www.imdb.com/video/vi3413033241?playlistId=tt0080846&ref_=tt_ov_vi).

Comment: It can't be Hawk because OP said it was terrible and this movie is eight shades of **awesome**

Comment: That is so definitely it. All the cliches I remember are right there in the trailer. (And it looks worse even than I remember.) I can't believe you got it in less than 20 minutes. (Sorry Valorum)

Comment: I remembered what this was as soon as I read your description of the elf with the macinebow.  I mean, how many epically bad sword swinger movies have one of those?

Comment: I'm also astonished at the cast of excellent actors they assembled for this.

Comment: @Valorum speaks truth, this can’t be terrible — it was a beloved movie growing up.

Comment: @ Silly but True:  I remember this as one of the great comedies of the period, along with Gor, and Krull.  Good times.